# Negative Error testing in iOS PayPal Sandbox mode

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to use negative testing to force errors in the iOS PayPal SDK but the payment is always accepted. I'm using iOS PayPal SDK v2.11.1 on iOS 8.3.

I'm in sandbox mode (the transaction confirmation says so too :) ), I've set the merchant account to Negative Testing mode, I'm trying to follow the instructions about setting the amount to the error number (e.g. error 10755 is entered in the transaction amount as 107.55). However, the instructions on the PayPal site don't directly relate to the iOS SDK but I've tried following the same principal.

Can anyone else successfully force errors in negative testing for iOS PayPal SDK? Hopefully, I'm just being a noob and missing a step somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: I heard from PayPal via Github and they said (in full)...

> "Unfortunately negative testing isn't really well supported by the REST API upon which the SDK is built."

...and with that they closed off the item.

I take this to mean there isn't any negative testing available in the iOS SDK so any reference to negative testing on their developer website doesn't apply to iOS. :-(

I'm guessing that's the same for Android.